# Sending multiple arguments to class with only one defined

Tags: python, django

I'm relatively new to Python and am coming from Java where everything is very explicit at compile time, so perhaps I am missing something here.  I have a class defined as such:

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    file = forms.FileField()
```

and then I'm using it like this:

```
...
form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
...
```

I'm passing two arguments into the class, so why doesn't this throw some sort of exception to me when ran?  It runs fine when I try it out.  I know that Python does accept variable amount of arguments, but I don't have the correct syntax for that in this case.  I would like to know why this is OK to do.

Comment: May be because the superclass `forms.Form` has a constructor that accepts any number of arguments.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I think you are right.  I mixed up the argument to a class being its superclass rather than a constructor argument.  I can't seem to find the actual documentation for the Form class constructor on the Django website though...

Comment: Django generally documents class constructors that you're expected to use (as opposed to subclass) in a bizarre form that's half-way between a constructor prototype and a class definition, like `class Field(**kwargs)`. For `Form`, they don't even do that, because it's constructed in various different ways for different uses. Let me edit my answer to explain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're mixing up classes and functions here.

This:

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
```

… is not a function definition, it's a class definition. It declares that the (only) superclass of `UploadFileForm` is `forms.Form`.

When you do this:

```
form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

The effect is similar to this pseudocode:

```
form = make new UploadFileForm
form.__init__(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

If you defined an `__init__` method, you'd get `form`, `request.POST`, and `request.FILES` as your arguments.

Since you didn't define an `__init__` method, you inherited the one from your parent class, so *it* gets those three arguments.

---

This is almost exactly like the following Java pseudocode:

```
class UploadFileForm extends forms.Form {
    static forms.CharField title = forms.CharField(50);
    static forms.FileField file = forms.FileField();
};

UploadFileForm form = new UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES);
```

Just as in Python, it works because you inherit constructors from the base class. Somewhere in `Form`, there's a declaration like this:

```
public Form(int verb, int obj) {
    // blah blah
}
```

And, in Python, the same thing is true:

```
def __init__(self, verb, obj):
    # blah blah
```

---

In other words, Python is almost exactly as explicit as Java (in fact, slightly more so, because the `self` parameter is explicit).

---

Also, note that your Python class attributes are equivalent to static members in Java. If you want normal instance members, you generally override `__init__` and set them as `self.title`, etc. there. (You don't *have* to do it that way—Python lets you add new members to your objects whenever you want. But it's the obvious place to do it.) For Django, this is actually pretty common—you create class attributes that the Django framework superclass uses to fill in initial instance attributes on your behalf.

---

Finally, the [reference documentation for Django's forms.Form class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form) doesn't actually show you the parameters, because there are (at least) four common different ways to construct `Form` subclasses, all of which are described separately:

```
MyForm() # creates an unbound form
MyForm(data) # creates a bound form
MyForm(data, files) # creates a bound file or image form
MyForm(initial=initial_data) # creates an unbound form with initial data
```

And some of these accept additional optional keyword arguments.

The actual source code [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L79) shows the real prototype:

```
def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, auto_id='id_%s', prefix=None,
             initial=None, error_class=ErrorList, label_suffix=':',
             empty_permitted=False):
```

Of course not all combinations of keywords make sense.

Anyway, you can see why they didn't try to explain `Form` in the simple way they do other types.

Comment: Yes, you are correct that I mixed up classes and functions.  Thanks for the Java equivalent too!  I think this makes sense now.  Do you mean superclass instead of subclass?

Comment: Good catch, yes. I originally wrote that `UploadFileForm` is a subclass of `forms.Form`, but then I turned it around because I think the other way around is more familiar to Java people, but left the word backward. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the recent edits, this actually cleared up a few recurring issues I always have when switching between Python/Java.